# Filterizr - Desando's imagesLoaded - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

First off, any help on this matter is greatly appreciated as I am so close to finishing my site and making it live.

I am a novice at best and am having trouble with overlapping images in my Filterizr photo gallery.

I have been researching this issue for days and have found dozens of posts and articles on the matter but cannot figure this out.

I have attempted - without success - to use Desandro's imagesLoaded script several times but my images still overlap.

I need to know what I am missing.

My images are setup in a Bootstrap grid like so:

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="filtr-container">

                    <!-- bridal gallery 1 photos -->

                    <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="1">
                        <a href="../../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-1.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="../../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-1.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>

                     <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="1">
                        <a href="../../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-2.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="../../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-2.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>

               </div>
      </div>
```

At the bottom of this page is my link to the script:

```
<script src="../../js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
```

and I have copied and pasted the entire imagesLoaded script into a JS file.

There is also a Filterizr JS file that I have not included here.

Yet the overlapping continues...

I see something about installing package managers on the imagesLoaded website but was not sure if this was imperative.

If it is, this could be my problem but I do not know how to install package managers.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated

So I checked the responsive image class and removed them and the images still stack and overlap.

Does anyone else have any ideas?

I feel like the images loaded JS file just isn't communicating with my html files.

Does it still work if the images are links to an alternate image source?

Should the image tags have a specific ID or class?

Comment: I see that your images have a class called `responsive-img`. That class may be adding like a float or a position absolute, that's a possible cause of your problem. Can you check what that class is actually doing? Use the chrome dev tools and see what kind of style your images have.

Comment: I didn't find it anywhere important so I removed the 'responsive-img' class from every image link and it still doesn't work.